# AddN must have the same size and shape with tf.estimator.LinearClassifier

Tags: python, tensorflow

My tensorflow application crashed with this error:

> Inputs to operation linear/linear_model/weighted_sum_no_bias of type AddN must have the same size and shape: Input 0: [3,1] != input 1: [9,1]

Appreciate if anyone can point me to the root cause.

I have a `tfrecord` file that has the following record:

```
features {
      feature {
        key: "_label"
        value {
          float_list {
            value: 1.0
          }
        }
      }
      feature {
        key: "category"
        value {
          bytes_list {
            value: "14"
            value: "25"
            value: "29"
          }
        }
      }
      feature {
        key: "demo"
        value {
          bytes_list {
            value: "gender:male"
            value: "first_name:baerwulf52"
            value: "country:us"
            value: "city:manlius"
            value: "region:us_ny"
            value: "language:en"
            value: "signup_hour_of_day:1"
            value: "signup_day_of_week:3"
            value: "signup_month_of_year:1"
          }
        }
      }
}
```

My spec is as follow

```
{
     'category': VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string),
     '_label': FixedLenFeature(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, default_value=None),
     'demo': VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string)
}
```

And my tensorflow code:

```
category = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key="category", vocabulary_list=["null", "14", "25", "29"],

demo = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key="demo", vocabulary_list=["gender:male", "first_name:baerwulf52",
                                                                          "country:us", "city:manlius", "region:us_ny",
                                                                          "language:en", "signup_hour_of_day:1",
                                                                          "signup_day_of_week:3",
                                                                          "signup_month_of_year:1"])

feature_columns = [category, demo]

def get_input_fn(dataset):
    def _fn():
        iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        next_elem = iterator.get_next()
        ex = tf.parse_single_example(next_elem, features=spec)
        label = ex.pop('_label')
        return ex, label

    return _fn


model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    model_dir=fp("model")
)

model.train(input_fn=get_input_fn(train_dataset), steps=100)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be because the LinearClassifier.train method expects the inputs as a batch and the code is calling:

```
ex = tf.parse_single_example(next_elem, features=spec)
```

This will work if you change the input_fn to

```
iterator = dataset.batch(2).make_one_shot_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
ex = tf.parse_example(next_batch, features=spec)
```

Comment: This is super useful aarkay! Thank you for the tip!

Comment: That it is. Changed batch size to -1 from a fixed size (2000), of input and label placeholders and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your feature `category` has dimension = 3 (3 values), but feature `demon` has dimension 9 (9 values) in your tfrecord. When using `LinearClassifier`, you need to ensure all features have the same dimensions.

Comment: I see. I thought tensorflow will automatically separate them into 27 records. Thank you.

Comment: @Mingxing is there any particular reason for that restriction ? Does that also imply that LinearClassifiers don't support [indicator_columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column) or [weighted_categorical_columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/weighted_categorical_column) ?